# jsdom - Option is not defined when running my mocha test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, jsdom

I am using node js tools for visual studio 2015 and I am writing mocha tests for my javascript and jquery, in my local environment I am using karma and chrome to run the tests and everything is working fine but for some reason I wanted to use jsdom to be able to run the tests from node js without using karma or the browser but one of the jquery plugin internally is doing an instance of Option (new Option) and using jsdom I get the reference error Option is not defined from karma I don't get any errors, the error seems obvious karma is using a real browser where the Option is defined and jsdom is not a real browser, is there any way to make my test work? debugging the test with jsdom I see that  HTMLOptionElement is attached to the window object created by jsdom but maybe the interface is not fully implemented and that is why the new Option is not working.

Here is the code of the test file

```
if (global.window) {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
} else {
    require('jsdom-global')();
    global.jQuery = global.$ = require("jquery");
}

var chai = require('chai');
var assert = chai.assert;
var expect = chai.expect;
var should = chai.should();

chai.use(require('chai-jquery'));
chai.use(require('chai-spies'));

var sourceFile = require('path_to_js_file');

describe('Test', () => {
    it('this is not passing', () => {
        var x = new Option;

        expect(1).to.equal(1);
    });

    it('this is passing', () => {
        document.body.innerHTML = '<input id="name"/>';

        sourceFile.init();

        expect($("#name").is(":focus")).to.equal(true);
    });
});
```

and my source file looks like this

```
function init () {
    $('#name').focus();
}

module.exports = {
    init
};
```

the error I am getting is:

```
ReferenceError: Option is not defined
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. I noticed that `Option` constructor is available from window if you assign window directly from jsdom. Below is the code that will give you access to `Option` constructor (however, I have to admit it's a workaround):

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
global.document = jsdom.jsdom(undefined);
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.Option = window.Option;
```

I'm using the latest implementation of jsdom: 9.12.0

Answer (score 0):

After running into this same issue, I noticed that the Option constructor was not, in fact, implemented in jsdom (as you suspected). See [issue #1759 on GitHub](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1759). I have [submitted a PR that fixes this issue](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/pull/1760).

At the time of this writing, the PR has not yet been merged, but I'll update this comment once that's been merged upstream.